# Power BI calculate average per category per week

Tags: powerbi, average, powerbi-desktop, power-automate

I am creating a work satisfaction survey for my company where every employee is supposed to fill out an MS Forms, which is then fed into Power BI by MS FLOW.

I want to get the average of a specific question, per team per week. So far I could not find an option to average out multiple entries together, not by day, but by week.

Does anyone know a good way on how to get this to work? Thank you very much in advance.

I have tried to write an AVERAGEX-Function, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: just to make it clear, I am not just interested in the average but also in relation to in which calendarweek specifically this average happened.

Comment: Update your question with code that you have tried. Weekly average or daily average?

Comment: I'd create a calendar table with the weeknumber in it. Either that or the first or last date in the week. Then you can add a matrix viz to your canvas, [QuestionID] on columns and [Week] on rows. AVERAGE([score]) on values